# VB.NET: insert multiple rows into an oracle database using ODP.NET

Tags: vb.net, oracle, sql-server-ce, odp.net

I have some records from a SqlCe as a result of a query similar to this:

```
select *
from tableName
where condition
```

Now, I want to insert those records into an existing table in a Oracle database that already contains data. I am using ODP.NET. Which is the best way (efficient) to insert all them at once and using a transaction to rollback if any problem appears?

NOTE: Both tables, in SqlCe and Oracle are the same, same columns and types.

Comment: Look into doing a batch insert.

Comment: Do you mean bulk insert?

Comment: This link calls them batch insert, but it's probably the same thing:  https://forums.oracle.com/thread/640673